# Finding Path to Current Desktop Picture

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

During the pre-sandbox era, there was a way of finding the file path to the current desktop picture.  I think one could use **Defaults** to read **com.apple.desktop.plist** (Library > Preferences) to see the path.  Now, I suppose we aren't allowed to access this file any more.  So is there an alternative way of finding the file path to the current desktop picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, `NSWorkspace` has [`desktopImageURLForScreen:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW19) If you've only got one screen, that can be gotten with `[NSScreen mainScreen]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. Caswell.  I'll check it out after running errands.